# Additional reasons for glFramebufferTexture2D returning invalid status with EAGLContext?

Tags: ios, swift, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

The general OpenGL-ES 2.0 documenation from Khronos seems incomplete, at least in regarding the iOS implementation https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glFramebufferTexture2D.xml

I have verified that none of the GL_INVALID_OPERATION conditions are met, but that's the status I'm being returned.

This operation goes through successfully on occasion, but it usually errors out for some reason.

It is failing within this function where I am connecting my framebuffer to a texture

```
  func fullColorFrameBuffer(_ fbo:GLuint, rbo:GLuint, texture:GLuint, size:CGSize) -> GLuint
{
    print("full color framebuffer fbo:\(fbo) rbo:\(rbo) texture:\(texture) size:\(size)")
    glBindFramebuffer(GLenum(GL_FRAMEBUFFER), fbo)
    glBindRenderbuffer(GLenum(GL_RENDERBUFFER), rbo)

    glRenderbufferStorage(GLenum(GL_RENDERBUFFER), GLenum(GL_RGBA8_OES), GLsizei(size.width), GLsizei(size.height))
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GLenum(GL_FRAMEBUFFER), GLenum(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0), GLenum(GL_RENDERBUFFER), rbo)

    self.assertNoGLError()

    glActiveTexture(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE0))
    glBindTexture(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), fbo)

    self.assertNoGLError()

    glTexParameteri(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S), GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T), GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER), GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER), GL_LINEAR);

    self.assertNoGLError()

    glTexImage2D(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), 0, GLint(GL_RGBA), GLsizei(size.width), GLsizei(size.height), 0, GLenum(GL_RGBA), GLenum(GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE), nil)

    self.assertNoGLError()

    glFramebufferTexture2D(GLenum(GL_FRAMEBUFFER), GLenum(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), texture, 0)

    self.assertNoGLError()

    let status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GLenum(GL_FRAMEBUFFER))

    if status != GLenum(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    {
        NSLog("failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", status)
    }

    self.assertNoGLError()

    return status
}
```

I am creating the handles here:

```
 fileprivate func createBuffers()
{
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLenum(LCAttributes.vertex.rawValue))
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLenum(LCAttributes.vertex.rawValue), 2, GLenum(GL_FLOAT), 0, GLsizei(2 * MemoryLayout<GLfloat>.size), nil)

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLenum(LCAttributes.texCoord.rawValue))
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLenum(LCAttributes.texCoord.rawValue), 2, GLenum(GL_FLOAT), 0, GLsizei(2 * MemoryLayout<GLfloat>.size), nil)

    glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebufferHandle)
    glBindFramebuffer(GLenum(GL_FRAMEBUFFER), framebufferHandle)

    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &renderbufferHandle)
    glBindRenderbuffer(GLenum(GL_RENDERBUFFER), renderbufferHandle)

    glGenTextures(1, &targetTexture)


    print("createBuffers fbo:\(framebufferHandle) rbo:\(renderbufferHandle) texture:\(targetTexture)")
}
```

Put simply; what are any other known reasons for the GL_INVALID_OPERATION being returned from this function on iOS? Alternatively, what are points of investigation for this bug? I've verified I'm on the correct thread, and that the same EAGLContext is used. I've verified the view has been setup correctly.

Comment: Since you mentioned threads: only one thread is accessing the context, right?

Comment: Also: what's up with `GLenum` all over the place?

Comment: Nothing is touching the context on another thread... I have a video player running on a separate queue. On the main thread, I'm copying over the texture into the buffer (which is failing to create here). I'll double check this process now.

All the GLenum is because swift is really ugly if you try to do GL work with it; you need to do quite a bit of casting for it to compile.

Comment: A lot of those casts are definitely wrong, like `GLenum(LCAttributes.texCoord.rawValue)`.  The first parameter is supposde to be a `GLuint`.

Comment: You're right -- I'll clean those up now. In Apple's implementation both GLuint and GLenum are represented by UInt32 so it's not affecting anything.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but I had similar troubles with iOS.  IIRC, it had to do with the RenderBuffer storage format.  Try this:

```
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, GLsizei(size.width), GLsizei(size.height));
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo);
```

If that doesn't do it, let me know and I'll post my entire RTT creation function.

Comment: Thanks!  this didn't fix anything. However, it did make me decide to check the framebuffer status before calling glFramebufferTexture2D. For some reason, that fixed the issue I'm having and I am completely unable to replicate it now.